# Python: check if method is static

Tags: python, static-methods

assume following class definition:

```
class A:
  def f(self):
    return 'this is f'

  @staticmethod
  def g():
    return 'this is g'

a = A()
```

So f is a normal method and g is a static method.

Now, how can I check if the funcion objects a.f and a.g are static or not? Is there a "isstatic" funcion in Python?

I have to know this because I have lists containing many different function (method) objects, and to call them I have to know if they are expecting "self" as a parameter or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I happens to have a module to solve this. And it's **Python2/3 compatible** solution. And it **allows** to test with method **inherit from parent class**.

Plus, this module can also test:

1. regular attribute
2. property style method
3. regular method
4. staticmethod
5. classmethod

For example:

```
class Base(object):
    attribute = "attribute"

    @property
    def property_method(self):
        return "property_method"

    def regular_method(self):
        return "regular_method"

    @staticmethod
    def static_method():
        return "static_method"

    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls):
        return "class_method"

class MyClass(Base):
    pass
```

Here's the solution for **staticmethod only**. But **I recommend to use the module** [posted here](https://gist.github.com/MacHu-GWU/0170849f693aa5f8d129aa03fc358305).

```py
import inspect

def is_static_method(klass, attr, value=None):
    """Test if a value of a class is static method.

    example::

        class MyClass(object):
            @staticmethod
            def method():
                ...

    :param klass: the class
    :param attr: attribute name
    :param value: attribute value
    """
    if value is None:
        value = getattr(klass, attr)
    assert getattr(klass, attr) == value

    for cls in inspect.getmro(klass):
        if inspect.isroutine(value):
            if attr in cls.__dict__:
                bound_value = cls.__dict__[attr]
                if isinstance(bound_value, staticmethod):
                    return True
    return False
```

Comment: This has a bug. It checks if *any* method with that name in the class's MRO is static. If there's a static method in a base class that's shadowed by a non-static method in a subclass, your function will output `True`.

Comment: I fixed the bug in this package https://github.com/MacHu-GWU/inspect_mate-project

Answer (score 23):

Lets experiment a bit:

```
>>> import types
>>> class A:
...   def f(self):
...     return 'this is f'
...   @staticmethod
...   def g():
...     return 'this is g'
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a.f
<bound method A.f of <__main__.A instance at 0x800f21320>>
>>> a.g
<function g at 0x800eb28c0>
>>> isinstance(a.g, types.FunctionType)
True
>>> isinstance(a.f, types.FunctionType)
False
```

So it looks like you can use `types.FunctionType` to distinguish static methods.

Comment: thank you for pointing me to the "types" module, I almost forgot about it.

Answer (score 14):

Your approach seems a bit flawed to me, but you can check class attributes:

(in Python 2.7):

```
>>> type(A.f)
<type 'instancemethod'>
>>> type(A.g)
<type 'function'>
```

or instance attributes in Python 3.x

```
>>> a = A()
>>> type(a.f)
<type 'method'>
>>> type(a.g)
<type 'function'>
```

Comment: Note that this only works if the object is instantiated(at least in python 3), so if you want to check if a method is static without instantiating the object, then this will not work.

Comment: @DuckPuncher Thanks! Youre correct, I have updated the answer.

Comment: @DuckPuncher In Python 3 you can check `isinstance(A.__dict__['f'], types.FunctionType)` and `isinstance(A.__dict__['g'], staticmethod)`

Answer (score 13):

To supplement the answers here, in Python 3 the best way is like so:

```
import inspect

class Test:
    @staticmethod
    def test(): pass

isstatic = isinstance(inspect.getattr_static(Test, "test"), staticmethod)
```

We use `getattr_static` rather than `getattr`, since `getattr` will retrieve the bound method or function, not the `staticmethod` class object. You can do a similar check for `classmethod` types and `property`'s (e.g. attributes defined using the `@property` decorator)

Technically, any method can be used as "static" methods, so long as they are called on the class itself, so just keep that in mind. For example, this will work perfectly fine:

```
class Test:
    def test():
        print("works!")

Test.test()
```

That example will not work with *instances* of `Test`, since the method will be bound to the instance and called as `Test.test(self)` instead.

Instance and class methods can be used as static methods as well in some cases, so long as the first arg is handled properly.

```
class Test:
    def test(self):
        print("works!")

Test.test(None)
```

Perhaps another rare case is a `staticmethod` that is also bound to a class or instance. For example:

```
class Test:
    @classmethod
    def test(cls): pass

Test.static_test = staticmethod(Test.test)
```

Though technically it is a `staticmethod`, it is really behaving like a `classmethod`. So in your introspection, you may consider checking the `__self__` (recursively on `__func__`) to see if the method is bound to a class or instance.

Another final caution for those doing more in depth introspection is that a `staticmethod` could be defined in a different class. The `__qualname__` will reveal whether the static method was defined in the class it is attached to or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Azmisov for `get_attr_static` to avoid calling the descriptor protocol ! I learnt something today :) ++

Answer (score 1):

Why bother? You can just call g like you call f:

```
a = A()
a.f()
a.g()
```

Comment: wow, indeed, you are right! I thought it would not work because I have the methods in a list, say `l = [a.f, a.g]`, and call them with `l[0]()` and `l[1]()`. But it works! Strange, I always thought normal methods need a reference to their containing object as first parameter. I mean, if I do `A.f()`, it is an error, while `A.g()` works, whereas `A.f(a)` also works fine.

Comment: This is obviously good answer (don't check if method is static!) to the problem, but it does not answer question in the title (check if method is static).

Comment: Right you are, Jiri. But I think it's good to have multiple ways of solving a problem, that's why I posted this answer. And it seems OP found it useful, so win/win :)

Comment: @DanielJung that works because when you do a.f, python creates bound method instance (it is bound to the object on which is is called). When you do A.f it returns unbound method (you can still call it using A.f(a)), while A.g returns a simple function.

Comment: Why bother? Because you are implementing a metaclass, decorator or writing code analysis tools.