# Python3: check if method is static

Tags: python, python-3.x, static, static-methods, introspection

Simmilar question (related with Python2: [Python: check if method is static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727059/python-check-if-method-is-static))

Lets concider following class definition:

```
class A:
  def f(self):
    return 'this is f'

  @staticmethod
  def g():
    return 'this is g'
```

In Python 3 there is no `instancemethod` anymore, everything is function, so the answer related to Python 2 will not work anymore.

As I told, everything is function, so we can call `A.f(0)`, but of course we cannot call `A.f()` (argument missmatch). But if we make an instance `a=A()` and we call `a.f()` Python passes to the function `A.f` the `self` as first argument. Calling `a.g()` prevents from sending it or captures the `self` - so there have to be a way to test if this is staticmethod or not.

So can we check in Python3 if a method was declared as `static` or not?

Comment: Can I ask why you're trying to do this?

Comment: of course, I'm making my own plugin framework and I want to inspect some interface declarations and I would love to know if something was declared as staticmethod or not :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
class A:
  def f(self):
    return 'this is f'

  @staticmethod
  def g():
    return 'this is g'
print(type(A.__dict__['g']))
print(type(A.g))

<class 'staticmethod'>
<class 'function'>
```

Comment: great! Could you please explain also why `A.__dict__['g']` gives something else than `A.g`?

Comment: `A.__dict__['g']` is different from `A.g` because functions are [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors). Function objects are descriptors because they define a `__get__` method, which is invoked by magic when the object is accessed using dot notation (like `A.f`). The descriptor protocol is how (for example) a _function_ gets transformed into a _bound method_ when called on an instance. Going through the `__dict__`, rather than using dot notation, bypasses the descriptor protocol.

Answer (score 6):

For Python 3.2 or newer, use [`inspect.getattr_static()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getattr_static) to retrieve the attribute without invoking the descriptor protocol:

> Retrieve attributes without triggering dynamic lookup via the descriptor protocol, `__getattr__()` or `__getattribute__()`.

Use `isinstance(..., staticmethod)` on the result:

```
>>> from inspect import getattr_static
>>> isinstance(getattr_static(A, 'g'), staticmethod)
True
```

The function can handle both instances and classes, and will scan the full class hierarchy for you:

```
>>> class B(A): pass
...
>>> isinstance(getattr_static(B, 'g'), staticmethod)  # inherited
True
>>> isinstance(getattr_static(B(), 'g'), staticmethod)  # instance, inherited
True
```

Answer (score 4):

I needed this solution and wrote the following based on the answer from @root

```
def is_method_static(cls, method_name):
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187973/python3-check-if-method-is-static
    for c in cls.mro():
        if method_name in c.__dict__:
            return isinstance(c.__dict__[method_name], staticmethod)
    raise RuntimeError("Unable to find %s in %s" % (method_name, cls.__name__))
```

Comment: This will only work for static methods that aren't inherited. You can use `inspect.getattr_static` instead of directly accessing `__dict__` if you want to support inherited static methods.

Comment: Thanks, getattr_static is new in 3.2.  My code runs in both Python2 and Python3