# Subtypes of python callables

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I define different callables as such:

```py
def f(): ...

class X:
    @classmethod
    def c(cls): ...

    @staticmethod
    def s(): ...

    #instance method
    def i(self): ...
```

Sure, we have `types.MethodType` and `types.FunctionTypes`, but I'd like to have types to 
distinguish more of the subtleties these callable objects have. Something like:

```py
assert isinstance(f, NormalFunction)
assert isinstance(X.c, ClassMethod)
assert isinstance(X.s, StaticMethod)
assert isinstance(X.i, InstanceMethod)
assert isinstance(X().c, InstantiatedClassMethod)
assert isinstance(X().s, InstantiatedStaticMethod)
assert isinstance(X().i, InstantiatedInstanceMethod)
```

## Appendix (edit)

Following this quest, I did this, and posting here because it may be useful to the reader:

```
                                MethodType  FunctionType  has_self  qualname_levels  dunders
name                                                                                        
class method                          True         False      True                2       27
instance method                      False          True     False                2       35
static method                        False          True     False                2       35
"instantiated" class method           True         False      True                2       27
"instantiated" instance method        True         False      True                2       27
"instantiated" static method         False          True     False                2       35
"plain" function                     False          True     False                1       35
lambda                               False          True     False                1       35
```

Code to do this, [here](https://gist.github.com/thorwhalen/4da0e43d815c8f89839cd7888b61a3fe)

Comment: Related: [Python3: check if method is static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187973/python3-check-if-method-is-static) - haven't found an adequate duplicate yet.

Comment: Not really sure what your question it- are you asking if there is a way to build your classes this way, or making a feature request on python?

Comment: I'd like to have the least hacky way to distinguish between various types of callable objects. Wtih `MethodType`, `FunctionType` and `hasattr(obj, '__self__')`, I can see how I could get to a function that gives me what I want. But that would (1) seem hacky and (2) not be as natural as the `isinstance(obj, SpecialType)` interface.

Comment: If you want a *hack* - try to implement something and post a question for each various problem.

Comment: @thorwhalen There's no difference between a function defined outside a class and one decorated with `@staticmethod`. You can try the following: `def f(): pass; class C: f = staticmethod(f); C.f is f`. And an "instantiated static method" doesn't make sense, since it's a function that lives in the class' namespace. There's a distinction between plain functions and (instance) methods which are bound to objects. A `classmethod` is an instance method of the class in that sense. What differs is the path taken during name resolution but you'll only see the result (the object bound to that name).

Comment: @a_guest, thanks, point taken (and avoiding going down the rabbit hole of what equality can/should mean). Yet, what I'm looking for is (1) distinguishing whatever **can** be distinguished (2) with the `isinstance(obj, SpecialType)` interface. See my updated table (added 3 more columns during my "Callable Subtypes" investigation).

Comment: @thorwhalen The question is why do you want to distinguish these in the first place? `__qualname__` depends on where the function was defined, not what kind of "type" it is. Compare `def foo(): ...; class C: foo = staticmethod(foo)` and `class C: @staticmethod def foo(): ...`. Both are equally valid ways to specify a static method on a class. `__qualname__` reveals where the underlying function has been defined (and won't be changed by `staticmethod`). Every instance method has a `__self__` attribute which is used for equality (`==`) comparison between instance methods.

Comment: ... The number of dunders obviously correlates with the object's type since it's that type that defines the dunders. So this doesn't add any information either.