# Exclude static members from documentation in Sphinx autodoc extension

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am using the Sphinx autodoc extension for documenting my Python project. I have the following in my docs for a class:

```
.. automodule:: ClassName
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

The class I am documenting has static members which I don't want to include in documentation. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score -1):

See the documentation of the option [`:exclude-members:`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html?highlight=exclude-members#directive-automodule) under `.. automodule::` for usage.

You need to add the option `:exclude-members: member1, member2`

Comment: I already have checked the documentation of `:exclude-members:` but by using it only single member names can be excluded. I have around 6-7 static methods which I need to exclude at once.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the meaning. Separate the single members with commas, i.e., `:exclude-members: member1, member2`

Comment: Okay. But is there any way in which we can say to exclude all static members without having to mention them one by one?

Comment: Not that I know of in a direct manner. You could remove docstrings from static members, then remove `:undoc-members:` from the reST source, but that's hacky. Suggest [submitting an issue](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues) to discuss adding this feature to Sphinx, or searching through the issue tracker to see if it's already suggested or solved.

Comment: @StevePiercy Couldn't he implement a user-defined `skip_member_handler` to skip static methods? I'm using such a handler to document e.g. marked `__init__` methods.

Comment: @Paebbels I considered that, but I don't know how to determine whether a member is static or not, or if it is possible. Maybe someone more experienced knows. If there is a way to make that distinction, then the Sphinx documentation on [Skipping Members](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html#skipping-members) provides the interface for a user-defined method.

Comment: The representation of a static method's type returns `<class function>` instead of `<class method>` for a normal method. Example: `print(type(myclass.mystaticmethod))` I think the module `inspect` (Python introspection API) should give more and better details. See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727059/python-check-if-method-is-static