# Python: Check if a method uses @staticmethod

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-methods

Is there any way to check if a method is decorated with `@staticmethod`? I need some function `is_static_method(func)` with does the following:

```py
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def a(x: int) -> int:
        return x
    
    def b(self, x: int) -> int:
        return x

def c(x: int) -> int:
    return c

m = MyClass()
is_static_method(m.a)  # True
is_static_method(m.b)  # False
is_static_method(c)  # False
```

So how does the function `is_static_method` would look like?

Comment: You can call the static method like this: `MyClass.a`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727059/python-check-if-method-is-static

Comment: @ZavenZareyan I know, but that doesn't makes it easier to code the function `is_static_method`.

Comment: Out of interest, why is this something you need to check programmatically?

Comment: @pask This does not help me, because it is alsy very difficult to access the class in which the method is definded.
@deceze I'm writing decorators that do some type checking and they don't work together with `@staticmethod` which is a desireable use case.

Comment: If the duplicate doesn't work for you, you should update the question to detail why exactly it doesn't…

Comment: You could try to access the source code `inspect.getsource(m.a)` and check if its a static function.

Comment: @DarkMath So in fact you are asking two questions: (1) how do I get the defining class of a method? (2) how do I identify a staticmethod? For (2), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25959545/984421).