# Passing an object to a decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I'm trying to create a Python file containing all of the decorators which I need to use in the rest of the program. These decorators are stored inside a class, which I called `Decorators`. Then I tried to add a decorator to check if the argument of a decorated function match with the argument types passed to the decorator itself (I took this kind of decorator from the example 4 at the site https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#examples, but I changed it a bit to better fit my style of coding). The syntax is like this:

```
class Decorators(object):

    """ Decorators class: contain all the decorators """

    @classmethod
    def argument_consistency(cls, *function_arguments_type):

        """ check the consistency of argument and their types of the decorated function """

        def check_arguments(function):

            """ check if the number of passed arguments is different from the number of accepted arguments """

            # check if the number of passed arguments is different from the number of accepted arguments
            if not len(function_arguments_type) == function.__code__.co_argcount:
                raise Exception("the number of passed argument is different from the number of the accepted arguments")

            def inner_function(*args, **kwds):

                """ check if the type of the passed arguments match with the requested ones """

                # iterate through the list of couples (argument, argument's type) and check for their match
                for (arguments, argument_types) in zip(args, function_arguments_type):

                    # remember that: {arguments} is the n-th argument passed to the function, while
                    # the {argument_types} is the n-th argument types. {args} is the entire list of arguments
                    # passed to the function; {function_arguments_type} is the entire list of types. So zip
                    # returns an iterator of tuples of element of {args} and {function_arguments_type} paired
                    # together, for example zip((1, 2, 3, 4), (a, b, c, d)) = ((1, a), (2, b), (3, c), (4, d))
                   
                    # check if the n-th argument type match with the one requested
                    if not type(arguments) == argument_types:
                        raise Exception(f"The argument {arguments} doesn't match the type, "
                                        f"which must be {argument_types}")

                # returning the passed function using the passed arguments
                return function(*args, **kwds)

            # changing the name of the inner_function to the {function}'s name
            inner_function.__name__ = function.__name__

            # return the inner function
            return inner_function

        # return the check_argument function
        return check_arguments
```

To test the previous decorator I created the simple class `A` whith a function `a`:

```
class A():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @Decorators.argument_consistency(str, str)
    def a(self, str1, str2):
        print(f"{str1} AND {str2}")

a = A()
a.a("ciao", "ciao2")
```

Obviously, when I decorated the function a I got an error (rised by the `argument_consistency` decorator itself). This because the length of the list argument types is different from the length of the list of passed arguments. The error appeared because I didn't put the `self` parameter. Understood this error, I tried to pass `self` to the decorator, but I got an error: `NameError: name 'self' is not defined` (this happens even if I pass `type(self)`); then I tried to pass the class `A` itself, but I still got the same error. So I tried to fix this by adding to the decorator one line between the `for` loop and the `if not type(arguments) == argument_types`:

```
if not (args.index(arguments) == 0 and argument_types is None):
    
    # check if the n-th argument type match with the one requested
    if not type(arguments) == argument_types:

        # the rest of the code
        pass
```

These line checks whether the first argument passed to the function decorator is `None`, then that means that the first parameter of the function is `self`, so the function doesn't proceed to check if `None` is equal to the type of the `self` parameter (which obviously is not). This way is very cumbersome and the opposite of elegant. Therefore I wonder if there is a way to avoid this fix and directly pass the `self` type to the decorator.

Comment: I think what you need - is to simply skip first argument if decorated function is a method/classmethod.
To check that you could use `inspect.ismethod()`. And to handle static methods, take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727059/python-check-if-method-is-static

Comment: thank you for your help! I'll try it out and I will let you know if it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a stub class for self argument for object/class methods

```
class selftype:
    pass
```

and pass it to decorator

```
@Decorators.argument_consistency(selftype, str, str)
def a(self, str1, str2):
    print(f"{str1} AND {str2}")
```

Then check in `inner_function` if the first type in decorator is your stub type:

```
def inner_function(*args, **kwds):
    for (argument, argument_type, i) in zip(args, function_arguments_type, range(0, len(args))):
        if argument_type == selftype and i == 0:
            pass
        # check if the n-th argument type match with the one requested
        elif not type(argument) == argument_type:
            raise Exception(f"The argument {argument} doesn't match the type, "
                            f"which must be {argument_type}")

    # returning the passed function using the passed arguments
    return function(*args, **kwds)
```

Not very elegant, but this works for both object/class methods and functions

```
class A():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @Decorators.argument_consistency(selftype, str, str)
    def a(self, str1, str2):
        print(f"{str1} AND {str2}")

a = A()
a.a("ciao", "ciao2")

@Decorators.argument_consistency(str)
def b(str1):
    print(f"{str1}")

b("a")
```

Also, if you want to use your decorator in pair with `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod`, make sure to apply your decorator first, otherwise it won't be able to access `function.__code__` attribute.

I quite liked the solution proposed by @go2nirvana in comments, but it didn't work for me, unfortunately. `inspect.ismethod(function)` returns `False` inside decorator functions calls, idk why.

Comment: thank you very much, I'm still trying to implement this, but I'll let you know if Ii will succeed

Comment: another thing, if I apply to the function I want to decorate the @classmethod decorato (apart from the @Decorators.argument_consistency) I got an error: `AttributeError: 'classmethod' object has no attribute '__code__'`. Any idea to avoid this kind of thing?

Comment: keep in mind that order in which you apply decorators matters. in this case you want to apply `@Decorators.argument_consistency` decorator first, so it grabs your undecorated function and checks arguments

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually noticed it and I wondered if it was a normal behaviour or a bug of my code. Thanks for your help. I'm not an expert programmer, this is one of the first time I look into more complex concepts, if there is a way I can retur the favor and help you let me know!