# Check if method is static from class without instantiating

Tags: python, class, static-methods

How to check if a method is static given a class, not an instance of a class. In some use cases, the instantiation of a class might have some consequences, and you might need to know if a method is static before any instantiation. Take for example the class:

```py
class MyClass:

  def method(self):
    pass

  @staticmethod
  def static_method():
    pass
```

I need a function `is_staticmethod` that gives:

```py
>>> is_staticmethod(MyClass, 'method')
False
>>> is_staticmethod(MyClass, 'static_method')
True
```

And as said before, this function should not instantiate the class. I tried to search for a question that already answered this, but got many results related to the case of class instances, which is not what I need.

Note: This is not a duplicate of [Python: check if method is static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727059/python-check-if-method-is-static)

Comment: Please, read the description. These don't answer it. They are for the case of class instances.

Comment: `isinstance(MyClass.__dict__['static_method'], staticmethod)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frist get it from the class's namespace, then use `isinstance`:

```py
def is_staticmethod(cls, m):
    return isinstance(cls.__dict__.get(m), staticmethod)


print(is_staticmethod(MyClass, 'method'))         # False
print(is_staticmethod(MyClass, 'static_method'))  # True
```

Comment: Does this have the caveat that it will fail when the method is defined in a parent class?

Comment: Regardless, this does answer the question as I wrote it.

Comment: @mauvilsa Since you are getting that method from class's namespace, No. I will not go to inheritance chain. If it wasn't there you get None back

Comment: I'd replace `cls.__dict__.get()` with `getattr()`

Comment: @OlvinRoght If you have a metaclass and it defines a descriptor with that name, then you're in trouble.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary, normally it shouldn't happen though

Comment: With `getattr` it does not work, try it out. However, with `isinstance(inspect.getattr_static(cls, m), staticmethod)` it works even with class inheritance.